# C++ How to declare a vector in the header, set size in constructor, then access

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I am having issues declaring a vector in the header, setting the default size in the constructor, then making it a function to do stuff in aDie.cpp. My known error is under the aDie.cpp declaration is incompatible for `void aDie::Frequency(std::vector<int> Vector());`. Any help would be appreciated to get me going in the right direction so that I have a vector that I can add values into. My code is below.

header aDie.h

```
#define aDie_H   
#include <vector>
class aDie {
public: 
    int i = 0; 
    aDie();
    void numRolls();
    void getSeed();
    void roll(); 
    void Frequency(std::vector<int> Vector());


private:
    int Rolls;
    int dSeed;
    int die1;
    int die2;
    int sum;

};
```

cpp aDie.cpp

```
#include "aDie.h"  
#include <iostream>  
#include <ctime>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

aDie::aDie() { //constructor sets values to default 0
    die1 = 0;
    die2 = 0;
    dSeed = 0;
    vector<int> Vector(6); //defaults to size six 
}
void aDie::numRolls() {
    cout << "Enter number of times for die to be rolled: ";
    cin >> Rolls;
    return;
}
void aDie::getSeed() {  //gets seed 
    cout << "Enter desired seed number: ";
    cin >> dSeed;
    srand(dSeed);
    return;
}
void aDie::roll() { //rng for one die
    die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
}
void aDie::Frequency(std::vector<int> Vector()); //store the rolls output by aDie::roll


}
```

.cpp Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "aDie.h"   
#include "aHistogram.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void game1();

int main() {
    game1();

    system("Pause");
}

void game1() {
    int i = 0;
    int Rolls = 0;

    cout << "Enter number of times for die to be rolled: ";
    cin >> Rolls;

    aDie Roll1; //calls default constructor
    Roll1.getSeed(); //calls seed  

    for (i = 0; i < Rolls; i++) {
        Roll1.roll(); //rolls die
        Roll1.//whatever my vector will be called

    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here, what should the method `frequency` be doing exactly?

Comment: I presume it should be storing the results of die rolls along with their corresponding frequency of occurrence?

Comment: I tried my best, but I was unable to find any vector that was declared in any header, here.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury yes it is suppose to store the rolls. I apologize and added the proper comment

Comment: I think you've confused the problems, you issue is not with how to declare a vector, but with how to use it. You have specified it as an argument, but want to use it as something else. Try to figure out more clearly your question. This time people have been nice and figured out what you wanted =)

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
void Frequency(std::vector<int> Vector());
```

is indeed invalid syntax, what you probably want to do is

```
void Frequency(std::vector<int> &v);
```

or

```
void Frequency(const std::vector<int> &v);
```

If you want to store the vector, then it should be member of the class:

```
class aDie {
//...

private:
    int Rolls;
    int dSeed;
    int die1;
    int die2;
    int sum;
    std::vector<int> vect;

};
```

and then the constructor could look like:

```
aDie::aDie()
    //constructor sets values to default 0
    : die1(0)
    , die2(0)
    , dSeed(0)
    , vect(6) //defaults to size six 
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your other doubt.

In header:

```
class aDie {
public: 
    int i = 0; 
    vector<int> Vector;
    aDie();
    void numRolls();
    void getSeed();
    void roll(); 
    void Frequency(const vector<int>& Vector);

private:
    int Rolls;
    int dSeed;
    int die1;
    int die2;
    int sum;

};
```

In .cpp:

```
aDie::aDie() { //constructor sets values to default 0
    die1 = 0;
    die2 = 0;
    dSeed = 0;
    Vector = vector<int>(6); //defaults to size six 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start reading up on the basics e.g. [here](http://www.learncpp.com/)(especially chapter 8).

But to answer your question, I try to give you a short walkthrough in the comments of the code.

```
// Header file A.h
#include <vector>
class A {
public:
    A();   
    void addNumbers();
    void addNumberIntoAnyVector(std::vector<int>& vec);

private:
    std::vector<int> myVector;
};

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"

// First option, initialize the member before the body executes.
// See e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html
A::A() : myVector(6) {
}

// Second option, resize it inside the body of you contructor
// Use only one of them, not both!
A::A() {
    myVector.resize(6);
}

// You have access to your member variables from within any member function
// So simply numbers to your myVector here.
void A::addNumbers() {
    for(int i=0; i<myVector.size(); ++i)
        myVector[i] += i;
}

// In this version you can pass any vector<int> instance as an argument
// and fill it with numbers.
void addNumberIntoAnyVector(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    for(int i=0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        vec[i] += i;
}
```

If that doesn't make sense to you, you should go back even further in the tutorials. I would really suggest to get some foundational knowledge first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to store the results of die rolls and their associated frequencies of occurrence in a container? If so, then this should achieve what you want (ignoring irrelevant methods):

```
#define A_DIE_H
#ifndef A_DIE_H

#include <map>  // for std::map
#include <utility> // for std::pair / std::make_pair

class aDie {
public: 
    aDie();
    void roll(); 
    int getFrequency(int _res) const;

private:
    // stores die roll results as Keys and frequency
    // of occurrence as Values
    std::map<int, int> result_freq_map;
};

#endif /* A_DIE_H */
```

and in the implementation file:

```
#include "aDie.h"   

aDie::aDie() { 

}

void aDie::roll() { //rng for one die
    int die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;  // roll the dice

    // try inserting result into map with occurrence of 1
    if (result_freq_map.insert(std::make_pair(die1,1)).second) {
        return;
    }
    // if result already contained in map, increment its associated value
    result_freq_map[die1]++;
}

// gets the frequency of occurrence of a given result _res
int aDie::getFrequency(int _res) const { 
    return result_freq_map[_res];
}
```

This is untested but it should work. I can address the rest of your code and how it could be structured better if you like as well.